# Eloquent taking too long with remote MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, laravel, rest, amazon-web-services, eloquent

I'm developing a web (Laravel) and iOS app that both consumes from a REST API that I'm also developing with Laravel. The API queries from a MySQL Database hosted at an AWS RDS instance.

When I set up both, the API and the app on localhost, and the API configured to connect my local Database (same machine as the apps and API) it works ok as expected, but the problem is when I setup the API to query from the AWS RDS Database instead of locally.
Simple queries made with eloquent, like

```
Product::where('brand_id', '=', $id)
               ->get()
```

takes like 10 - 15 mins to complete, but if I do the same query by using the query builder, for expample;

```
DB::select('select * from products where brand_id = ?', [$id]);
```

works fine.

Executing the query directly on MySQL or running Product::all() at the Laravel Tinker works as intended with local API / Remote DB setup.

EDIT:

Here is what I get when I execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE products`

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SKU` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `price` double(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `product_details` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `material_and_care` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `material` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `care` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `colors` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `made_in` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `size_chart` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `size_chart_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `published` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `featured` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `promo_title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `promo_caption` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `shipping_height` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `shipping_width` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `shipping_length` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `shipping_weight` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `is_vertical` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `products_category_id_foreign` (`category_id`),
  KEY `products_brand_id_foreign` (`brand_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `products_brand_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`brand_id`) REFERENCES `brands` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `products_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `subcategories` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=501 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

My Product Model:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, CascadeSoftDeletes;

    protected $cascadeDeletes = [
        'items',
        'options',
        'images',
        'sizes'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'sku',
        'name',
        'price',
        'description',
        'product_details',
        'material_and_care',
        'material',
        'color_1',
        'color_2',
        'color_3',
        'care',
        'made_in',
        'size_chart',
        'size_chart_url',
        'brand_id',
        'category_id',
        'published',
        'featured',
        'promo_title',
        'promo_caption',
        'shipping_weight',
        'shipping_height',
        'shipping_width',
        'shipping_length',
        'is_vertical'
    ];

    protected $appends = [
        'interests',
        'brand',
        'options',
        'sizes',
        'items',
        'images',
        'comment_count',
        'discount',
        'suits_me_count'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'created_at',
        'deleted_at',
        'updated_at',
        'subcategory'
    ];

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::addGlobalScope(new PublishedProductScope);
    }

    public function getDiscountAttribute() {
        return $this->discount()->first();
    }

    public function getSuitsMeCountAttribute() {
        return $this->suitsmes()->count();
    }

    public function getCommentCountAttribute() {
        return $this->comments()->count();
    }


    public function getImagesAttribute(){
        return $this->images()->pluck("url");
    }

    public function getInterestsAttribute() {
        return $this->interests()->get();
    }

    public function getBrandAttribute(){
        return $this->brand()->first();
    }

    public function getOptionsAttribute(){
        return $this->options()->get();
    }

    public function getSizesAttribute(){
        return $this->sizes()->get();
    }

    public function getItemsAttribute(){
        return $this->items()->get();
    }

    public function interests() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Interest', 'product_interest');
    }

    public function brand() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Brand');
    }

    public function options() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductOption');
    }

    public function sizes() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductSize');
    }

    public function items() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductItem');
    }

    public function images() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductImage');
    }

    public function comments() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductComment');
    }

    public function suitsmes() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'wishlist', 'product_id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function discount(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Discount');
    }

    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Subcategory', 'category_id');
    }

}
```

And my Brand Model:

```
class Brand extends Model
{


 protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'phone_number',
        'birth_date',
        'ssn',
        'street_address',
        'street_address_2',
        'city_address',
        'state_address',
        'postal_code_address',
        'legal_name',
        'dba',
        'tax_id',
        'street_business_address',
        'street_business_address_2',
        'city_business_address',
        'state_business_address',
        'postal_code_business_address',
        'destination_fund',
        'email_business',
        'phone_number_business',
        'account_number_fund',
        'routing_number_fund'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'created_at',
        'deleted_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    protected $appends = [
        'images'
    ];

    public function getImagesAttribute()
    {
        return $this->images()->get();
    }

    public function getBillboardPicturesAttribute() {
        $pictures = [$this->billboard, $this->billboard2, $this->billboard3, $this->billboard4];
        return $pictures;
    }    

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_brand_role', 'brand_id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function getInterestsAttribute() {
        return $this->interests()->pluck('interest_id');
    }

    public function interests() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Interest', 'brand_interest', 'brand_id', 'interest_id');
    }

    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }

    public function images() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\BrandImage');
    }

    public function categories() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category');
    }

    public function getCatalogAttribute() {
        return $this->categories()->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
    }


}
```

Comment: Wow seems weird, try `Product::where(array("product_id"=>$id))
               ->get()`. I am using RDS but I dont have any issues.

Comment: If your `brand_id` is not primary_key than you need to apply an index on `brand_id` field.

Comment: Do you have the same problem with other tables? If no, restart your server.

Comment: brand_id has an index, and I have the same problem with all the tables

Comment: Do you have default eager loading for any relations configured within your `Product` model?

Comment: Have you run an explain to confirm the SQL generated is identical in both cases?  Is Product.where not perhaps joining against other tables and performing an unexpected table scan?

Comment: @fubar no, I don't have any eager loading.

Comment: @mcfinnigan how do I that?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE products`.

Comment: @RickJames I just added the result to my original questing.

Comment: I'm not inclined to believe that it's an issue with your db. What do your models look like?

Comment: @WhyAyala I just added my models.

Comment: @miguelglz well you're not doing anything weird with the model definitions. You would normally expect a difference in performance between query builder and eloquent because the former just fetches the results without hydrating them to a model where the latter performs the hydration process. Another more common term for hydrate would be populate. How many records are being returned with this query?

Comment: Can you provide the output of the following code please? `die(Product::where('brand_id', '=', $id)->toSql());`

Comment: @WhyAyala I'm fetching 500 products from 12 brands. What I find weird is that if I run `Product::where('brand_id', '=', 25)->get()` with the tinker it works ok, it shows the results in less than 1 sec.

Comment: @WhyAyala I'm putting a log before and after the `Product::where('brand_id', '=', 25)->get()`, the former logs as soon as the function is executed, and the second one dosen't. Should I try to return a view without anything else besides the query results?

Comment: You could try that. The fact that it works fine in tinker makes me think something else is happening during your request response cycle that's slowing it down.

Comment: This is almost definitely not a query optimization issue but rather something going on during the actual request like @WhyAyala mentioned. Especially seeing as when you use Tinker it responds fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is this piece of code in your `Product` model:

```
protected $appends = [
    'interests',
    'brand',
    'options',
    'sizes',
    'items',
    'images',
    'comment_count',
    'discount',
    'suits_me_count'
];
```

> These properties are relationships, and so they result in multiple
>   joins every time Eloquent reads/returns a row.

This query: `DB::select('select * from products where brand_id = ?', [$id]);` doesn't result in any joins and is a select query from a single table. That's why when you compare results, you find a dramatic difference in query time.

There are 2 possible solutions:

**1. Remove the appends**

Remove the appends and whenever you need a relationship use the `with` function

**2. Make the append properties hidden**

You could add this code to your `Product` Model:

```
protected $hidden = [
    'created_at',
    'deleted_at',
    'updated_at',
    'interests',
    'brand',
    'options',
    'sizes',
    'items',
    'images',
    'comment_count',
    'discount',
    'suits_me_count'
];
```

When you need a property just use `$product->makeVisible('property_name')`. Otherwise, by default, these properties won't be loaded or queried

Comment: why would it function normally in tinker though?

Comment: Not sure, could be quite a few reasons. Perhaps brand_id 25 specifically doesn't have any relations or perhaps it doesn't have many products. I don't think the testing is apples to apples. Whatever the case may be, the code pretty much shows that these relations are being loaded, hence causing the multiple joins, so I'm pretty sure this is the real reason

Comment: Interesting, I was not aware of `appends` feature.

Comment: The attributes in `$appends` only apply when converting a model into an array (`toArray()`) or JSON (`toJson()`). It's possible that in Tinker it is not running such a conversion, but in the app is being passed to the view or converted as such.

Comment: You were right. As soon as I commented the appends everything started loading smoother. Thank you.