# Prevent model hydration on Eloquent queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, performance, eloquent

Is it possible to have an *eloquent query builder* return `StdClass` rather then `Model`?

For example `User::where('age', '>', 34)->get()` returns a `Collection` of `User` models.

Whereas `DB::table('users')->where('age', '>', 34)->get()` returns a `Collection` of `StdClass` objects. Much faster.

Therefore:

Is it possible to prevent hydrating eloquent models and return `StdClass` objects as a *database query builder* would, but still leverage the usefulness of an *eloquent query builder* syntax?

Comment: Did you try casting the response `->toArray()` and then recursively walking it to do some magic with `return (object) array_map(__FUNCTION__, $array)`

Comment: This negates the reason for doing this: Performance. Otherwise yes its very very simple.

Comment: This is *severely* premature optimization.

Comment: If you are attempting to do  this on a table with 800 rows, sure its not an issue. Although if the table has 10,000+ rows. Yes we are talking 20-30 seconds to hydrate Eloquent alone. Premature optimization? No i'd say its time to optimize. And no im not talking about casting a query response to a collection "return StdClass rather then Model" is what the question states...

Comment: Also @ceejayoz how could you possibly know its premature optimization from my question? You have zero information on the use case... Your question is a case of a premature statement, you should optimize it.

Comment: It's clearly premature optimization, because if a couple milliseconds makes a difference to your application, you'd be ditching Eloquent entirely, as "the same easy complex relation queries" would be outweighed by your critical need for thousandth-of-a-second performance tweaks.

Comment: Did you read my comment? We are talking 10,000 plus rows. We have actually timed the hydration process into an Eloquent model. Its taking upwards of 8-9 seconds. "you'd be ditching Eloquent entirely" ... YES thats what the question is stating... Exactly that. Using `Eloquent Query Builder Syntax` can we execute it and NOT hydrate Eloquent models. Id not waste my time on 300ms.

Comment: @ceejayoz the question has been reworded to be very very verbose.

Comment: Adding a bunch of rant doesn't change my opinion of the question. "But I should not have to get into the why - this is a question and answer forum" simply isn't the case here - the **why** helps prevent us from wasting enormous amounts of time on [**XY problems**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). (Aggressively tagging me a week later is silly, too.)

Comment: What you are saying is essentially "There could never be a case where you would want to do this" rather than "Maybe there is a use case - albeit rare" than answering the question rather than divulging how you would solve a seperate issue.

Comment: QueryBuilder and Eloquent have almost identical syntax, so you're not losing much in terms of "elegant syntax" by using `DB::table()`. You are losing things like custom query builders, scopes, model events, etc. But if you just want to power through a pile of data, DB::table to start a query still gives you the builder we all know and love.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, is possible using the 'getQuery' or 'toBase' method. For example:

```
User::where('age', '>', 34)->getQuery()->get();
```

or

```
User::where('age', '>', 34)->toBase()->get();
```

Comment: Do you know if this still uses scopes?

Answer (score 18):

In my opinion,

> Hydrating models rarely affects application performance

There are so many ORMs out there and if you look at any framework, these questions keep popping up - but the truth, as I've come to realize, is that ORMs hardly affect performance.

> More often than not the culprits are the queries themselves and not
> the ORM

Let me give you a few examples of why Eloquent models may perhaps be slower than DB facade queries:

**1. Model events**:

When you have [model events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events) (such as saving, creating, etc.) in your models, they sometimes slow down processing. Not to say that events should be avoided, you just need to be careful when and when not to use them

**2. Loading Relationships**:

Countless times have I seen folks load relationships using [appends](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) lists provided by Eloquent and sometimes models have 5-10 relationships. That's 5-10 joins each time you fire an Eloquent query! If you compare that with a DB facade query, it would definitely be faster. But then again, who's the real culprit? Not the ORM, it's the queries (with the extra joins!)

As an example, not so long someone asked [a question on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48814659/eloquent-taking-too-long-with-remote-mysql-db/48936062#48936062) and he/she wondered why an Eloquent query was slower than a raw one. Check it out!

**3. Not understanding what triggers an Eloquent query**

This is by far the most prominent reason why people think ORMs are slower. They usually (not always) don't understand what triggers a query.

As an example, lets say you want to update a `products` table and set the price of product #25 to $250.

Perhaps, you write in your controller, the following:

```
$id = 25;
$product = Product::findOrFail($id);
$product->price = 250;
$product->save();
```

Then, your colleague says hey, this is super slow. Try using DB facade. So you write:

```
$id = 25;
DB::table('products')->where('product_id', $id)->update(['price' => 250]);
```

And boom! It's faster. Again, the culprit isn't the ORM. It's the query. The one above is actually 2 queries, the `findOrFail` triggers a `select *` query and the `save` triggers an update query.

You can and should write this as a single query using Eloquent ORM like so:

```
Product::where('product_id', 25)->update(['price' => 250]);
```

**Some Good Practices for Query Optimization**

1. **Have your database do most of the work instead of PHP**: E.g. instead of iterating over Eloquent collections, perhaps frame your DB query in such a manner that the database does the work for you.
2. **Mass Updates Over Single Updates**: Pretty obvious. Avoid saving models in for loops, yuk!
3. **For heavy queries, use transactions**: DB transactions avoid re-indexing on every insert. If you really need to call say thousands of inserts/update queries in a single function call, wrap them into a transaction
4. **Last but not the least, when in doubt check your query**: If you're ever ever ever in doubt, that perhaps the ORM is the real culprit - think again! Check your query, try and optimize it.

If the ORM is slowing things down, use obervers or the [Laravel debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) to compare the queries with and without the ORM. More often than not, you'll find that the queries are different, and the difference isnt in hydration but the actual queries themselves!

Comment: Firstly, thank you. I'm not here to hate on Eloquent, ORMs have their place. I agree with you completely. Regarding optimization of the underlying query. That we are already undertaking. Although I just want to be clear on the parameters of the question: Is this possible. Not should it be done.

Comment: Nope, not that I'm aware of. If you want StdClass objects to be returned, I think the only way is to use the DB facade. But then of course, you would need to say goodbye to all the Eloquent features such as relationships, model events, etc. Although like I said earlier, 10k rows is a really small set of data and I'm 100% sure, hydrating 10k rows cannot take 20-30 seconds! If you wrap it in a transaction and use optimal queries, don't think it should be a problem. My guess is that your queries aren't optimized

Comment: Yeah you may be correct! Although for the sake of SO I'd like the answer recorded. Perhaps someone will need it one day...  I wrote this as we have so many data sources we actually use - Mongo, Elasticsearch and MySQL all unified by our Repository interface https://gist.github.com/andrewmclagan/aaf49eaf067d8d2a6a88f08f1db23cc9

Comment: Notice in that link we has `asModels()` `asObjects` and `asArrays` because we have `Hydrators` for MongoDB and Elasticsearch....

Comment: Bear in mind that many queries will not actually load the models (e.g. your final example in #3), and thus will avoid both hydration and model events.

Answer (score 0):

It is inefficient to have small models and load them. What ->toBase() does is lowering the inefficiency. Memory inefficiency for 4-5 model persisted attributes with average length between 5 and 10 when loading model is 90+ percent. What is even more inefficient is having many and small models and as definition of hell - when there is a lot of traffic on them. Then you should think of another persistence design for that data. Wisely choose when model is the right home for a piece of data.